# Jupyter Notebook object has no attribute

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04, leptonica, python-tesseract

I'm getting an error to convert images into text when I'm working on Jupyter notebook using ubuntu. but when I'm working with windows I'm successfully retrieving text from Images. Please see on Image  [click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOt6x.png)

Comment: please put the error message you get (AttributeError) into the description here -- by providing clear information here you will get more answers

Comment: Are you saying this same script runs on Jupyter Notebooks in Windows but not on Ubuntu?

Comment: Your error message is implying that the image reference is expected to have a split method defined (probably a string), that doesn't seem to be result that the read you are doing is returning.

Comment: @RufusVS Yes, It's work on Jupyter Notebook in Windows but not in ubuntu.

Comment: I install tesseract inside Leptonica on my working dir  it's seem like working but pytesseract doesn't working However I Install pytesseract using dockerfile.

Comment: After you read in the image, do a print(type(image)) or print(repr(image)) on both your Windows and Ubuntu versions and make sure they return the same thing on each platform.  Also: Are both your Windows and Ubuntu notebooks running the same python kernel (2.7 or 3.x)?